# Como hacer un update para reemplazar el valor de un campo con el que se encuentra en otra columna de la misma tabla

Tags: mysql

Quisiera saber como podría hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo una tabla de con dos columnas: `nombreuno` y `nombredos`.

La columna `nombreuno` tiene como registro `'julio'` y la columna `nombredos` tiene un registro `'jose'`.

Lo que busco es que a todos los nombres que tenga las columna `nombredos` me los coloque en la columna `nombreuno`

Comment: Pon un pequeño ejemplo, con varias filas, del estado actual de los datos y de lo que esperas obtener.

Comment: por lo que logro entender, puedes usar esta sentencia: `update <NombreTabla> set nombreuno  = nombredos where <tu_filtro>`, pero estas seguro que no deseas guardar o respaldar la información de columnauno?

Comment: ¿Te interesa conservar el valor almacenado en la columna `nombreuno` de alguna manera o al final, tanto `nombreuno` como `nombredos` tendrán el mismo valor?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo deseas hacer directamente desde SQL, entonces te tengo una respuesta:
La idea detrás de lo que deseas hacer es nested querys. O tambien llamadas Subquerys.
Se basa en, como su nombre lo indica, hacer una query dentro de otra para obtener valores.

Puedes encontrar información sobre ello aquí [SQL Sub querys](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm)

Disculpa que no coloque un ejemplo en concreto, tiene tiempo que no toco lenguajes de consulta, así que es muy probable que el código que escriba no funcione por x razón.